# Reorder legend items in bokeh

Tags: python, plot, legend, bokeh, legend-properties

In the example from the documentation

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import RdBu3
from bokeh.plotting import figure

c1 = RdBu3[2] # red
c2 = RdBu3[0] # blue
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    y=[2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    color=[c1, c2, c1, c2, c1, c2],
    label=['hi', 'lo', 'hi', 'lo', 'hi', 'lo']
))

p = figure(x_range=(0, 7), y_range=(0, 3), plot_height=300, tools='save')

# Note legend field matches the column in `source`
p.circle( x='x', y='y', radius=0.5, color='color', legend='label', source=source)
show(p)
```

is there a way to change the order of the items in the legend to ('lo', 'hi') instead of ('hi', 'lo') without reordering the items in all of the original arrays?

[image]

Comment: I tried inspecting the `p.legend[0].items`, as recommended in the docs, but there's only one item there.

Comment: I think you can find the answer why there is only one legend item [here](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/cant-order-legend-entries-in-hbar-plot/3816/5).

Answer (score 0):

This workaround allows to accomplish this task:

```
from math import nan

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import RdBu3
from bokeh.plotting import figure

c1 = RdBu3[2] # red
c2 = RdBu3[0] # blue
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x=[nan, nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    y=[nan, nan, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    color=[c2, c1, c1, c2, c1, c2, c1, c2],
    label=['lo', 'hi', 'hi', 'lo', 'hi', 'lo', 'hi', 'lo']
))

p = figure(x_range=(0, 7), y_range=(0, 3), plot_height=300, tools='save')

# Note legend field matches the column in `source`
p.circle( x='x', y='y', radius=0.5, color='color', legend='label', source=source)
show(p)
```

Comment: This will work just for this specific example, but there is an interest to be able to define the sequence of entries shown in a general way, e.g. for histograms.